# Custom code similar to DATEDIFF_BIG in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014. I am facing a problem when I want to compare previous row date time with current row in second. The error states:

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts
>   separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff
>   with a less precise datepart.

SQL Server 2016 solved this issue with `DATEDIFF_BIG` but that function is not supported in SQL Server 2014. And currently there are no plans to change database server with SQL Server 2016.

Any alternative solution would be appreciated.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by A.MDetailID) as Row
  , DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.CreatedDate, LEAD(A.CreatedDate,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY A.CreatedDate))
FROM dbo.tbl_VehicleLiveMovementDetail A
```

Comment: Can you share an example of your data with the issue?

Comment: @Jaime It's an example:

 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by A.MDetailID) as Row, DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.CreatedDate, LEAD(A.CreatedDate,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY A.CreatedDate))

   FROM dbo.tbl_VehicleLiveMovementDetail A

Comment: If the difference in seconds causes an overflow, maybe you need to use minutes instead to get smaller numbers

Comment: @ marc_s but i need to compare with second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code,

```
LEAD(A.CreatedDate,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY A.CreatedDate)
```

[LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function provides access to a row at a given physical offset that follows the current row but at the last row `LEAD` function not found any subsequent row so it return default datetime `'1900-01-01 00:00:00'`
. For this case you need to compare with default datetime like as following....

```
case when LEAD(A.CreatedDate,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY A.CreatedDate)='1900-01-01 00:00:00' then A.CreatedDate else LEAD(A.CreatedDate,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY A.CreatedDate) end
```

which would not be optimum solution for you.

If you use `LEAD(A.CreatedDate,1,A.CreatedDate)` instead of `LEAD(A.CreatedDate,1,0)`, you would not be required to use any `case` statement and the solution would be optimum like as following...

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by A.MDetailID) as Row,
DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.CreatedDate, LEAD (A.CreatedDate,1,A.CreatedDate)OVER (ORDER BY A.CreatedDate))Result
FROM dbo.tbl_VehicleLiveMovementDetail A
```

Comment: instead of `LEAD(A.CreatedDate,1,0)` use `convert ( datetime, LEAD (A.CreatedDate,1,A.CreatedDate)`.. And the remove `case when ... then .. else ... end`